# It is possible to programmatically send information on the R/G/B data pins to a VGA monitor during the Vertical Blanking Interval (VBI)?

Tags: windows, directx, hardware

I'm trying to send information like close captioning to a special VGA monitor that can read the RGB data lines during the BVI. The data is used for synchronization with other devices.

I cannot find information regarding any Windows API to do so. Is there any OS that has these services? Is there any support in the standard video boards to do this kind of tweaking?

The closes I get is some DirectX API functions that can parse "Line 21" data from DVD streams but nothing to encode "Line 21" data to be send out of the VGA connector.

Comment: "Line 21" is NTSC closed captioning.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need more information about exactly how the monitor is doing this. It may be using some sort of extension to DDC/CI. If so, you *may* be able to access it reasonably easily (starting with Vista, Windows has [some functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd692964.aspx) for working with DDC, though mostly with the basic, widespread capabilities like adjusting brightness and contrast).

If you need to work with older versions of Windows than Vista, [some](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/lib/softosd.shtm) third party [software](http://www.nicomsoft.com/wini2cddc/) supports that.

It could also be doing something else entirely -- in which case, it's open to question not only whether Windows will support it, but whether you may need a special video card to use it at all. Windows can only use what the video card's driver (and ultimately, the hardware) support, so unless it is something well known like DDC, chances are pretty good that a generic video card won't support it.

Comment: But HDMI, for instance, already support out-of-band data (in the Video Data Period on TMDS) so new HDMI video boards must be able to send kernel/user generated data. Nevertheless, I can't find any information regarding how to encode user data in HDMI either.

Comment: Also, as far as I understand, DDC information is generally not in sync with video, so Windows does not provide a way of sending the data simultaneously with the certain change in the image. I don't now if Linux can provide such synchronization.